# Simulate a 2D point mass moving along y=x^2 in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math

I have a mixed set of differential and algebraic equations for which I have found the analytical solution in MATLAB. It concerns a point mass moving along a 2D curve constrained by `y=x^2`.

How would I go about using an ode-solver in MATLAB (or something else if it's easier) to simulate the ball rolling over the curve? The animation I can do myself, I'm more concerned with finding the velocities, `xd yd`, for each consecutive step. That's where I kind of get lost.

These are the equations of motion which I've derived using Lagrange multipliers. Hence the `lambda`. The `lambda` is the reaction force. I can calculate the accelerations, `xdd ydd`, but I also need the velocities in the state if I want to properly simulate this, I assume.

```
% Symbolic functions
syms y x xd yd xdd ydd
syms m g lambda

% Parameters

A = [m 0 -2*x; 0 m 1; -2*x 1 0];
X = [xdd ydd lambda].';
b = [0 -m*g -2*xd^2].';

sol = A\b % these are the states stored in X
```

Comment: if you know its accelaration you can just calculate its velocity and position. x=dx+dx*dt, dx = dx+ ddx *dt. (d -> derivative, dd second derivative). Than just loop over time...

Comment: You just need to write the equations of motion for the mass along the curve: Serret-Frenet formulas: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas.  Once you have them, Runge-Kutta numerical integration ought to be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

So if you work out your problem using the lagrancian you would get the following formula seen below (see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47154/ball-rolling-in-a-parabolic-bowl). The k-value comes from y=kx^2 (can be 1 for your example).

So rewrite this in the following form.

[image]

Now you just use

```
 ddx=   Formula seen above..
 x  =  x + dx  *dt
 dx = dx + ddx *dt
 t  = t  + dt 
 y  = k*x*x
```

You make a loop with a sufficient small dt, and update you x-position velocity and acceleration.
Now you need 
to specify the following starting values -> x0 dx0 ddx0 and dt.
I hope this helped
Cheers:)